# What is the replacement of FormDataCollection in Asp.Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to use FormDataCOllection in Asp.Net core web api project. As per the documentation it is not there in .net core.

How can I still use it? Or What has replaced it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.form) property of `HttpContext.Request` which will return an [`IFormCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection) instance.

Answer (score -1):

FormDataCollection is normally type of the information/class/model sent by forms or grid edit or sumbit links. You can simply use the string as input parameter and then using Json, convert it to the class type you've expected.
Here is an example:

```
public string NewUser(string values)
    {
        var message = "";
        try
        {
            var newUser = new User_Detail();
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, newUser);
            db.User_Detail.Add(newUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            message = "User cretaed successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = "An error happened in this method.";
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
    }
```

So, PopulateObject converts your input string (values in this example) to the class you've expected, something similar to FormDataCollection you've needed.
Note: JsonConvert is in Newtonsoft.Json namespace